# Migrating mysqli query to wp_query

Tags: wp-query

I have created my site with pure PHP-code, and now started to migrate it to Wordpress platform. Changing authentication from own system to WP-user meta was quite easy. But when i use user session data for site functions, i have to query now user meta instead of simple MySqli-queries.

My old query is like below. Page is getting `$provider`, what is eMail-address. And with it, can fetch rest of needed values from database:

```
$provider=$_GET['provider'];
$providername=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT name,email,phone_number,pic,province,feedback FROM $usertable WHERE email='$provider'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($providername)) {
$provname=$row['name'];
$provemail=$row['email'];
$provpic=$row['pic'];
$provphone=$row['phone_number'];
$provprovince=$row['province'];
$feedback=$row['feedback']; }
```

Simple and working well. But do this same with WP-query. I tried to find solution from number of threads, but no. In my mind didn't get it as it so differently done or samples do not just fit to my need here.

Can you help a little bit here? I think that this query can be made with WP-query as simple.

Answer (score 0):

On the url below you can find all the information that you need regarding wp_query.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Yes, i found that also. But there is lot of different queries, but none of how to show the results. This is my problem with wp-queries in common.

Comment: @Matti - not sure what results you are talking about  - The Wp-query loops through the posts and pages and gets the data from by using for example the_title(); the_content(); so on and so forth

Comment: Yes, but if i need it as variable like in mysqli-guery $provname what to use for presenting views and functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i figure this out by self.
With Wordpress, there is used get-method, not queries.

```
$provinfo=get_user_by( 'email', ''.$provider.'' );

if ( ! empty( $provinfo ) ) {
$provname = '' . $provinfo->first_name . ' ' . $provinfo->last_name;
$provemail = '' . $provinfo->user_email . '';
$provpic = get_avatar( $provemail, 30 );
$provphone = '' . $provinfo->mobile_number . '';
$provprovince = '' . $provinfo->province . '';
$feedback = '' . $provinfo->feedback . ''; }
```

It was simple. But as starting to learn WP-code, hard to change mind to quite different direction after base PHP :-)